# Совместимы ли методы из библиотеки Delphi с P/Invoke?

Tags: c#, delphi, .net

Совместимы ли методы из библиотеки, написанной на Delphi с P/Invoke?
И если нет - есть ли какая либо возможность сделать их совместимыми?

Есть доступ к исходникам .dll.

Comment: на Delphi нативная библиотека написана?

Comment: Да, нативная библиотека написана на Delphi.

Comment: а почему методы должны быть несовместимы? :-) по большому счету не важно на чем написана нативная библиотека

Comment: Ну, например, потому что даже стандартные вызовы из C++ не сработали, пришлось в заголовочных файлах объявлять метод старым СИ синтаксисом, например: `extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) char* Method(char buffer[]); }`

Comment: какая связь с Delphi?

Comment: Хм, интересный вопрос. А как выглядят сигнатуры у методов? Вы можете посмотреть при помощи dumpbin.

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, у Дельфи может быть свой name mangling.

Comment: @VladD, там это так же настраивалось

Comment: @Grundy: Я не в курсе. Если вы знаете как, говорите :)

Comment: @VladD, 15 минут, поищу статью по которой делал, у автора была таже  самая проблема.

Comment: @VladD, https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/DLL#Delphi

Comment: Ага, если функцию можно подключить через dllimport, то P/Invoke должно работать.

Comment: @VladD, ту статью не нашел, но ошибку понял, ее разжевали тут: http://rsdn.ru/forum/dotnet/1820352.hot  Цитата: "Судя по исходнику C++ прога использует C++ Calling Conversion. Проверить это можно с помощью depends.exe, если названия фунцяй имеют вид @#$@#$connect@#$#@%#^$^, значит так оно и есть. Используйте модификатор __stdcall или WINAPI в описании экспортируемой процедуры." и "Про extern "C" не забываем. "

Comment: У вас хороший, интересный вопрос для специалистов среднего и выше уровня. Было бы здорово, если бы вы восстановили его и кратко описали  найденное решение.

Comment: @VladD, у делфи есть [ещё подвох](http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=44306&p=6766549#p6766571)

Comment: @Qwertiy, это про stdcall, и cdecl?

Comment: @Grundy, неа, они финт с this вторым параметром изобрели. Всегда вторым. По ссылке довольно детально расписано.

Comment: @Qwertiy, мне кажется это больше к проблеме реализации плагинов к конкретной программе, чем к delphi и dll

Comment: @Grundy, там то, что все делфи-разработчики без малейших проблем писали как обычный класс, оказалось несовместимым с другими языками. С вероятностью 99% этот фокус затрагивает всё делфи, а не конкретную программу.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, надо конкретный пример кода :-)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Вторым параметром? о_О А если у метода 10 аргументов?

Comment: @VladD, возвращается код ошибки (как принято в com), результат исполнения метода - первым аргументом (вместо последнего), а всё остальное просто сдвигается на один. Почитай ту тему - там расписано, что происходит и что должно.

Comment: @VladD, если 10, то будет [result, this, 10 параметров]

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ого, не знал. Ну да, это такой типа бинарный формат для исключений.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала - стоит посмотреть в исходниках, с каким соглашением о вызовах функции из библиотеки экспортируются.

Если там `stdcall` или `cdecl` - то такая функция без проблем может быть вызвана через P/Invoke. Если же там соглашение не указано - то так просто не получится.

В таком случае, если исходники библиотеки менять нельзя - самым простым решением будет прослойка из еще одной библиотеки на Delphi:

```
procedure Foo(...); external 'MyLib.dll';

// ...

procedure Foo_Std(...); stdcall;
begin
  Foo(...);
end;

// ...

exports
  Foo_Std name 'Foo';
```

Comment: Проблема именно в том, что у них в методах нестандартное соглашение о вызовах: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/494011/#comment583436_494011

Comment: @VladD если написать ключевое слово `stdcall` - то соглашение о вызовах *внезапно* становится стандартным :)

Comment: @VladD если бы у них было все насквозь нестандартно - то программы на Паскале не могли бы использовать сторонние библиотеки и компоненты COM - но этого не происходит. Что WinAPI, что тот же DirectX - в Delphi работают без трюков с параметрами.

Comment: Ага, это важно. Может быть, стоит отметить важность этого ключевого слова в ответе.

Comment: При чем тут "важность"? У меня весь ответ про это ключевое слово и написан :)

Comment: Хм, и правда, не дочитал текст :)

Comment: @All, ответ Павла абсолютно верный, не понимаю почему никто не плюсутет) Ясно, коротко, по существу и с простым примером.